# Enumeration concept in Scala - Which option to take?

Tags: scala

Scala programmers have a few options when defining enumerations:

1. Use [Scala Enumeration](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration)
2. Mimic enumerations using Scala sealed case objects.
3. Use [Scalaz Enum](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Enum)
4. Use [Java Enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)

When researching the best practices around enumerations in Scala, I stumbled upon the Google post entitled [Enumerations must DIE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/8RWkccSRBxQ%5B1-25-false%5D) and also [this](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html) blog which highlights a potential problem using the Scala `Enumeration` class. Both these references have cast a negative shadow over the Scala `Enumeration` class.

Option 2 seems like a lot of work and with regards to Option 3, I have not used the Scalaz library as of yet so I would interested to know the experience others have had with using `Scalaz` `Enum`. The final option is to inter-op with Java which I try to avoid since I like to take a purist approach in my Scala programming.

The point of this post is to leverage the community experience in order to detail the context(s) when one option would be preferred over another and also in which context(s) would using a particular option be wrong or likely to cause serious issues, so that an informed decision can be made in choosing one option over another. I am not looking for opinions but rather concrete use context(s) when one option is better than the other(s); opinions are likely to get this post closed down so please avoid that.

Comment: I'm very hopeful for this question. It feels like there should be / needs to be a definitive answer for which enum approach to use. I recently discovered enum paradise, but haven't tried it, so I threw it in the ring. I think this question is valid because it puts forward the list of options, as opposed to asking for recommendations.

Comment: There is also Viktor Klang's gist (https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/1057513) and chaotic3quilibrium's gist (https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/57add1cd762eb90f6b24). I believe the latter is meant to refine the former with exhaustiveness checking on `match` statements.

Comment: I've written a small overview about scala Enumeration and alternatives, you may find it useful: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/

Answer (score 4):

I have used both of the first two options in the past depending on the circumstances.  I can't speak for the other options but I would be reluctant to use Java Enums.  Generally I will always prefer a Scala solution over a Java solution where one is available.  I would also be reluctant to introduce a library just for Enumerations.  It seems a bit heavy to introduce a large library to accomplish such a small task, especially when there are built in ways to accomplish that task.  It might be different though if the library was offering other features that I wanted which were not built in.

Part of it depends on what you need the enumeration to accomplish.  If you need it just to create a set of discrete values, then I would lean towards Option 2.  It really isn't much work at all.  You can make it more complex if your needs require it, but the most basic scenario is:

```
trait MyEnum
case object MyValue1 extends MyEnum
case object MyValue2 extends MyEnum
```

If on the other hand you need something that actually provides you with an "ordered" set of discrete values that you can iterate over, obtain numeric values for etc, then I might lean more towards the Scala Enumeration.

Comment: Please can you expand your post to include why you are reluctant to use Java Enums and 3rd party libraries. That would aid others in making informed decisions. Thank you.

Comment: Added the requested explanations.

Comment: Two minor suggestions: (1) use a `sealed trait`, (2) wrap all case objects in a companion object with the same name as the trait. Imho this results in a more beautiful scoping, e.g., `MyEnum.Value1`, and typically allows to use shorter names for the values, since you are not polluting the parent scope (e.g. `MessageType.Ping` instead of say `PingMessageType`).

Comment: The above is the most basic example.  There are lots of ways you can refine it.  I agree, a sealed trait would be a better solution.  And typically I would probably wrap it in a companion object.  But technically neither of those things are required for the most basic solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Scalaz Enum**

- Enumeration concept in Scalaz is modelled on the Haskell `Enum`
- Provides useful operations on sequentially ordered types
- Develop rich enumerations through sealed case classes
- Iterate over those sealed case classes in a type-safe manner
- More analysis is required on the part of implementer to define the notion of order for the type that is sought to be enumerated.
- Required to define `succ` and `pred` functions
- Required to override the `order` function from the `Order` type class.

**Example**

```
import scalaz.Ordering.{EQ, GT, LT}
import scalaz.{Enum, Ordering, Show}

sealed abstract class Coloring(val toInt: Int, val name: String)

object Coloring extends ColoringInstances {

  case object RED extends Coloring(1, "RED")

  case object BLUE extends Coloring(2, "BLUE")

  case object GREEN extends Coloring(3, "GREEN")

}

sealed abstract class ColoringInstances {

  import Coloring._

  implicit val coloringInstance: Enum[Coloring] with Show[Coloring] = new Enum[Coloring] with Show[Coloring] {

    def order(a1: Coloring, a2: Coloring): Ordering = (a1, a2) match {
      case (RED, RED) => EQ
      case (RED, BLUE | GREEN) => LT
      case (BLUE, BLUE) => EQ
      case (BLUE, GREEN) => LT
      case (BLUE, RED) => GT
      case (GREEN, RED) => GT
      case (GREEN, BLUE) => GT
      case (GREEN, GREEN) => EQ
    }

    def append(c1: Coloring, c2: => Coloring): Coloring = c1 match {
      case Coloring.RED => c2
      case o => o
    }

    override def shows(c: Coloring) = c.name

    def zero: Coloring = Coloring.RED

    def succ(c: Coloring) = c match {
      case Coloring.RED => Coloring.BLUE
      case Coloring.BLUE => Coloring.GREEN
      case Coloring.GREEN => Coloring.RED
    }

    def pred(c: Coloring) = c match {
      case Coloring.GREEN => Coloring.BLUE
      case Coloring.BLUE => Coloring.RED
      case Coloring.RED => Coloring.GREEN
    }

    override def max = Some(GREEN)

    override def min = Some(RED)

  }

}
```

---

**Example Output:**

```
val f = Enum[Coloring]
println(f.fromToL(Coloring.RED, Coloring.GREEN))

res1 : List(RED, BLUE, GREEN)
```

Comment: Note that this code requires a small change to actually use the additional functions like `|->`, `succ`, `-+-`. If you use:
`case class Coloring(val toInt: Int, val name: String)
 
  object Coloring extends ColoringInstances {
 
    val RED = Coloring(1, "RED")
    val BLUE = Coloring(1, "BLUE")
    val GREEN = Coloring(1, "GREEN")
  }
`
Scalaz will find the correct implicits for the added functions. Complete example can be found here: http://www.smartjava.org/content/scalaz-features-everyday-usage-part-1-typeclasses-and-scala-extensions

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [Enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum). Description taken from their documentation:

> Enumeratum is a type-safe and powerful enumeration implementation for
>   Scala that offers exhaustive pattern match warnings, integrations with
>   popular Scala libraries, and idiomatic usage that won't break your
>   IDE. It aims to be similar enough to Scala's built in Enumeration to
>   be easy-to-use and understand while offering more flexibility,
>   type-safety and richer enum values without having to maintain your
>   own collection of values.